# Use Multiple Tab Spacing Settings and Comment in VS Code When Using pandasql

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, pandasql

Recently I've been coding a lot of SQL in my Python projects via pandasql. The minor issue I encounter is the different spacing schema used in Python (4 spaces) and SQL (2 spaces)... so I cannot just press the *tab* button.

In the case of comment, SQL uses `--` while Python uses `#`. It would be nice if when you press `CTRL+/` and the in-line comment would appear accordingly.

I'm just wondering if it is possible to somehow add a tag so that VS Code will know that certain part of the code in the .py file is actually a SQL statement and will use 2 spaces when I press *tab*?

```py
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as psql


df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',
                 parse_dates=['date'])

q = '''
SELECT
  *
FROM
  df
--WHERE
  --date > '2019-01-01'
'''
psql.sqldf(q, locals())
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the two-vs-four-space indentation, a simple answer is that you probably don't need to do this. Do *you* care about having your Python code indented with four spaces and your SQL indented with two? If you do care, why? There is no benefit to you in doing that. SQL is not indentation-sensitive as Python is. You could write your SQL query all on one line and it would work the same:

```
q = 'SELECT * FROM df'
```

Or you can use four spaces just like Python. You could even indent the whole thing just for fun:

```
q = '''
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        df
'''
```

It just doesn't matter to a SQL engine, so write your code in the way you find most readable and convenient, and don't worry about trying to match some irrelevant coding standard just because your source file includes two different languages.

I do have one suggestion on your Python formatting. You're currently using column alignment, carefully lining things up with spaces so one function argument is below the prior one:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',
                 parse_dates=['date'])
```

In virtually any programming language, you are better off using only indentation instead of alignment. In an indentation-only style, that code might look like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    'data.csv',
    parse_dates=['date']
)
```

What is the advantage of this style? Suppose you later decide that `pd` was a little too cryptic and you would prefer to spell out `pandas` for clarity. After you make that text substitution, the column-aligned code will look like this:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('data.csv',
                 parse_dates=['date'])
```

Oops. Now you have to manually go through every place you used that name and add extra spaces.

If you use the indentation-only style, this problem won't happen:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(
    'data.csv',
    parse_dates=['date']
)
```

Changing the name from `pd` to `pandas` didn't affect the formatting at all.

Update: I see you just added a question about making Ctrl+/ work in the embedded SQL code as well as the Python code. That one I don't have an answer for, sorry! I was only addressing your original question about the indentation. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion in the Python indentation part, I never thought about it before. I just edit my question to also address the issue with using `CTRL+/` to comment-out code.

Comment: Regarding `indentation-only` style, is it possible to set VS Code to auto-format my code to be that style instead of the default `column alignment` when I press the Ctrl+K, Ctrl+F sequence? Would be great to be able to do that to reformat some of my codes to that style.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you put your SQL queries in a different file with a different file extension you can change your settings on a per-file type basis, e.g. `"[python]": {"editor.tabSize": 4}, "[sql]": {"editor.tabSize": 2}`.